# Make the "No comment needed" option more obvious

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, low-quality-posts

This is what the "Recommend Deletion" option panel looks like:

> [image: Recommend Deletion options]

Every option *except* for "No comment needed" is in bold and has a great multiple line excerpt about when to use the option.  They are very pronounced.

In comparison, "No comment needed" has a much lower visibility.  It has no use case and has no font weight.

I understand that that option is probably the most useless option to moderation since it gives moderation no context about why the post should be deleted. I can only assume that it's intended use is for egregious posts that really do need no comment such as complete gibberish.

Thing is, I don't think I ever noticed the option before today. I just failed a low quality queue audit because I didn't know which option to choose for spam. I believe that the audit wanted me to choose "No comment needed".  I would have chosen the link only option, but it seems like that option is specifically telling me not to use it for spam.

Please give this option the same attention that the other options have. It might make sense to put it last in the options list.  Alternatively, let me provide my own comment so I can still give moderation context while recommending deletion.

Comment: FWIW, audits don't care what comment you leave (if any).  They only care that you recommended deletion or decided it was ok ("looks OK" or "edit")

Comment: Actually, the option *does* have a practical use. Sometimes I write my own comment. Another time, I used for an answer that was clearly a troll. Furthermore, if somebody has already commented with the review comment *outside* review, then I upvote the comment because the system doesn't merge comments in that case.